# how to remove post comment box from my website?

Tags: comments

i want to remove comment section from my home page of website[image]

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to remove comment from home only, Then follow these steps.

1. Click on edit of homepage.
2. Click on Screen Options and the top right.
3. From there check Discussion.
   [image: Check Discussion]
4. After this below text editor you will see new option box for discussion.
5. Deselect Allow comments from there 
   [image: Deselect Allow Comments]

Let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Discussion -> Uncheck "Allow people to post comments on new articles"

[image]